# Does ORM lead to bad coding practices?

Tags: php, orm, coding-style, doctrine

We're using ORM in PHP on our team, and I've noted in two separate projects that, even though we've specifically talked about good MVC design at length, that ORM appears to be allowing people to do DB queries from the View layer and creating difficult-to-maintain code.

I'm leaning towards the opinion that ORM makes it too easy to make queries under the covers that the programmer doesn't think about. By returning ORM objects to the view layer the programmer is essentially leaking a database connection to a layer that should not have it.

Am I thinking about ORM correctly here? If so, why is it so darn popular? If I'm not thinking about it correctly how *should* I address these issue?

Comment: I've answered, but it would be of interest to know what ORM you are using.

Comment: Also, have you tried simple architecture rules, such as "thin controllers, fat models"?

Comment: Symfony isn't an ORM. `:)` Propel or Doctrine perhaps?

Comment: I mean to say the built-int Doctrine ORM module.

Comment: I've always been of the mindset: fat service layer thin controller & thin DAO layer (in this case ORM layer, though personally I'm more partial to a separate model and self-built DAO layer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that having small ORM calls in the view layer is *necessarily* bad. For example, I might have `foreach (Category::getAll() as $Category):` as the loop to list categories on a page. The connection doesn't leak into the scope of the view (or at any rate it certainly shouldn't) since it is encapsulated by the ORM. I *could* assign the result of this call in the controller and pass the array of objects to the template (and I certainly will with more complex calls) but imo trivial cases are fine in the view.

The biggest problem with ORMs in my experience is the growth of "n+1" database query counts. Normally a one:many list on a screen can be rendered from a single query, but ORMs make it extremely convenient to use a primary loop with one table, and then to do an individual select for each instance of the secondary table. This is inefficient, but you'll only notice when your database starts to creak with the expanded number of queries it is having to deal with.

The best guard against this is to ask your developers to run a toolbar in dev mode (such as the Symfony2 toolbar, PHP Debug or similar) which shows them the number of queries required to build a screen. When trivial screens start needing more than 50 queries (or whatever ceiling you specify) then they need to refactor.

Also, it's worth choosing an ORM that has a reasonably expressive query syntax, otherwise your devs will be shirking back to "raw SQL" mode, which defeats some of the reasons of having the ORM in the first place. For the same reason - and Daniel makes this point well - offering training to your devs on using ORMs effectively is a great idea.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that you're not thinking about it correctly. ORM by and of itself does not promote bad practices, at least, not in the way you're experiencing it.

ORM is a tool, just like any other framework, api or whatever, you can use it correctly or not.

It sounds more like the problem is that the developers in your team doesn't have a clear understanding of the MVC pattern. I'd start with addressing that issue first.

I think it's quite a common problem with the MVC pattern that developers tend to use the views and controllers for things that they aren't supposed to do. The reasons might be many, but whenever you work with something like this, I beleieve the problem usually starts with something similar to this thought:

> "It such an simple little thing I'll just do it here instead, there's
>   no point doing it all over there."

Basically when trying to decouple design and business logic there will always be situations when it's easier to implement some piece that actually belongs in the business layer in the presentation layer. It mustn't mean that the developer is bad, but it might show some lack of experience or laziness. I know I've been guilty of this exact thing several times, like when developing for Android (never professionally though :)).

How about trying to figure out some sample-case that uses some of the bad practices that you've noticed and have some sort of coding-dojo where you as a team make that code nice and correctly implemented, and if you have time, show the actual benefits of having stuff where they belong. I'd strongly advice against using actual code unless you've written it yourself or the developer responsible for that code is okay with being mangled in front of other devs. But this obviously depends on the culture in your company and if the developers are interested and open for these kind of things. I personally would love having similar things at my workplace.

Answer (score 1):

Doing queries from views is a bad practice. You can do it, but is better doing it through the controller via Ajax Requests or whatever you consider suitable.